# TypeError: 'Image' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch

I am running the model below and after splitting the image and trying to assign the image back I get the error message stating.

```
    sample[:, :, 0] = 0
TypeError: 'Image' object does not support item assignment
```

I have tried different approaches to assigning the image back to the sample but that didn't help. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many Thanks

Here's the code I am using to do the data loading:

```
import os

import numpy as np
import torch
from PIL import Image
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torchvision import transforms, utils
from torchvision.transforms import functional
#from torchvision.transforms import Grayscalei
import pandas as pd
import pdb
import cv2
from cv2 import imread
from cv2 import resize

class CellsDataset(Dataset):
    # a very simple dataset

    def __init__(self, root_dir, transform=None, return_filenames=False):
        self.root = root_dir
        self.transform = transform
        self.return_filenames = return_filenames
        self.files = [os.path.join(self.root,filename) for filename in os.listdir(self.root)]
        self.files = [path for path in self.files
                      if os.path.isfile(path) and os.path.splitext(path)[1]=='.png']

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.files)

        path = self.files[idx]
        sample = Image.open(path)
        sample = np.asarray(sample, dtype=np.uint8)
        sample = cv2.resize(src=sample, dsize=(1024, 1024))
        sample = functional.to_grayscale(sample, num_output_channels=3)

        sample[:, :, 0] = 0
        sample[:, :, 1] = 0

        if self.transform:
            sample = self.transform(sample)

        if self.return_filenames:
            return sample, path
        else:
            return sample

    def duplicate_and_transform(self,transforms):
        currfilelen = self.__len__()
        
        for pind in range(0,currfilelen-1):
            path = self.files[pind]
            sample = Image.open(path)
            samplet = transforms(sample)
            # save the transformed images and save the associated counts:
            newpath = path[:-4]+'trans.png' #path[:-4] is the path without the .png extension.
            samplet.save(newpath,"PNG")
            metadata = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(self.root,'gt_red.csv'))
            metadata.set_index('filename',inplace=True)
            count = metadata['count'][os.path.split(path)[-1]]
            samplet.save(newpath,"PNG")
            f = open(self.root+'gt.csv','a')
            basepath = os.path.basename(path) # strip away the directory list and just get the filename
            f.write(basepath[:-4]+'trans.png,'+str(count)+'\n')
            # return the new file names and add to self.files.
            self.files.append(newpath)
            #pdb.set_trace()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are directly operating on a PIL object. you have to convert it to a numpy array first and then manipulate the values:

```
sample = Image.open(path)
sample = np.asarray(sample, dtype=np.uint8)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting a different error now.     sample = sample.resize((512, 512))
ValueError: cannot resize this array: it does not own its data - Any idea please? I tried to comment this lineout but got an error message which says: TypeError: img should be PIL Image. Got <class 'NoneType'> Many Thanks

Comment: I got rid of the error message by using sample = sample.reshape((512, 512)) but now getting an error message: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 4194304 into shape (512,512). Any suggestions please?

Comment: Oh I see. you can do:
sample = cv2.resize(sample, (512, 512)) # sample should be a numpy array

Comment: I have updated my code above but I am now getting another error :     sample = functional.to_grayscale(sample, num_output_channels=3)
  File "/Users/nubstech/opt/anaconda3/envs/Cells_Counting/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/functional.py", line 869, in to_grayscale
    raise TypeError('img should be PIL Image. Got {}'.format(type(img)))
TypeError: img should be PIL Image. Got <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: that's because to_grayscale method operates on a PIL Image. you can either convert the numpy array to PIL and run the function or directly convert the numpy array to grayscale using:
sample = cv2.cvtColor(sample, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

Comment: Thanks a lot! You fix one thing it breaks other bit, Now, i get  line 44, in __getitem__
    sample[:, :, 0] = 0
IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: Is it possible to specify the no of channels in v2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY?

Comment: you can actually remove the lines:
sample[:, :, 0] = 0
sample[:, :, 1] = 0
Because when we convert to grayscale we are removing the channels itself.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! I need to be able to separate the image to Red and Green, so I can count the cells in the microscopy image. If I try to separate by channel then convert to grayscale i get an error message about the number of channels.

Comment: Oh I see. then it would be better to convert the numpy array into PIL Image and then convert to grayscale and back to numpy array. so after resize and before converting to grayscale you can do: sample = Image.fromarray(sample) and then after converting to grayscale you can convert back to numpy array as you are doing in line 7 of __len__ function